# Raspberry Pi 3 stuck in rebooting after finishing the install

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, power-supply, usb-power

recently, i bought Raspberry Pi 3 and started to setup the stuff! first of all, i used laetest NOOBS OS and its just finished the install and after that stucked in Rebooting! then bought another SD card(SanDisk 16GB) and its dosent booting up even at the first and the LED is off!

Then downloaded Raspbian jessie Image and formated the SDCard with SDFORMATER and installed the image with Win32DiskImager and i get this:

[image]

and stuck in rebooting loop!

-- UPDATED THE PICTURE

Comment: Can you take a better pic (not tiled, straight on and closer to the monitor). All I can tell from the above is that something about USB is the last thing printed to the screen. Does it fail at a specific point every time? Is there an error printed to the screen? How are you powering the Pi? Have you removed all USB devices and tried booting (assuming the last thing on the screenshot is correct). Which LED's if any are lit? Have you looked at this http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting?

Comment: -1. What you posted is more of a sight test than it is of a technical question. Can you read text on your own picture?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev please take a look, i changed the picture

Comment: That is great what about the rest of my list. As the picture still does not show the problem.

Comment: @SteveRobillard do you think this happened because the power supply?

Comment: It is possible. We might be able to actually answer if yopu supoply the info requested, and run through the troubleshooting link I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, low voltage in the kit from power supply, the normal range is (4.75 - 5.25v) but in my kit, the current voltage was 1.6v and it cause the rebooting loop.

thank you guys.

http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems